# Can a power mosfet switch small loads?

Tags: mosfet

A lot of power mosfets have a really nice and low RDS(on), but their charts never seem to go down near 0A. For example the NTD3005L:

[image: drain current down to 5A]

The chart shows the value down to something like 5A. What happens below that? Could I use the to switch a 10mA load, and is the RDS(on) just undefined, or would it not work?

Comment: It sure can. They just do not bother to measure down to that level in their lab the same way you do not characterize how a pickup truck behaves when towing a styrofoam cup. Expected usage.

Comment: @DKNguyen awesome, thanks! I couldn't find any 'minimum ID' parameter, so that's what I was hoping.

Comment: Unintended consequence....  Power MOSFETs have bigger gate areas, thus much larger capacitance than a small-signal MOSFET.   If your circuit is basically DC  (i.e. the gate rarely changes state) and you don't care whether the switching takes milliseconds or microseconds to occur, probably a non-issue.   But if you're switching at a high frequency, this higher capacitance could cause you unnecessary trouble.

Comment: @DKNguyen +1 for the image of a truck, belching black smoke, tires spinning, towing a styrofoam cup ... lol

Answer (score 4):

> *I couldn't find any 'minimum ID' parameter*

Look up \$\color{red}{I_{DSS}}\$ in the data sheet of the device - this tells you what the leakage current of the MOSFET is when it's turned off. Clearly, to be effective as a switch you don't want \$\color{red}{I_{DSS}}\$ to encroach any appreciable distance towards your normal operating current AND, by the same token you don't want it to semi-power the load when it's meant to be inactive.

Typical values of \$\color{red}{I_{DSS}}\$ range from 100 nA (really good) through 1 uA to 250 uA (not so good for light loads). An IRFZ44 (a pretty commonly used device) is 25 uA but this can rise to 250 uA at higher temperatures.

If your load is very light, you'll probably do better using an analogue switch to turn your load on and off because these devices can be rated down to leakage currents of less than 10 nA with an on-resistance of 1 ohm. Horses for courses.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep that in mind. You're probably right in that there's a better tool for the job. I was leaning towards a small signal mosfet for this, but I already need some power mosfets for something else so I was hoping the square peg might fit in the round hole.

Comment: [What to do when you have a good answer and there are no more good answers likely to arrive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKrn6.png). But wait a day or two first.